# Programming uart of cortex-m3 (Microsemi SmartFusion 2)

Tags: arm, uart, cortex-m, baud-rate

I am programming a basic uart echo on cortex-m3,
**but i am getting giberish on putty**

used 100 MHz clock frequency for cortex-m3

Baud rate 57600

What might be the reason for giberish output ,does **uart** baud rate be in some multiple or in some relation with cortex-m3 clock frequency or the Amba bus frquency has some relation with baud rate

program is given below -->

```
#include "drivers/mss_uart/mss_uart.h"


mss_uart_instance_t * const gp_my_uart = &g_mss_uart0;

/*==============================================================================
 * main function.
 */
int main()
{
    size_t rx_size;
    uint8_t rx_buff[1];

    /* Turn off the watchdog */
    SYSREG->WDOG_CR = 0;

    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Initialize and configure UART.
     */
    MSS_UART_init(gp_my_uart,
                  MSS_UART_57600_BAUD,
                  MSS_UART_DATA_8_BITS | MSS_UART_NO_PARITY | MSS_UART_ONE_STOP_BIT);

    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Send greeting message over the UART.
     */
    MSS_UART_polled_tx_string(gp_my_uart,(const uint8_t*)"\n\r\n\r**********************************************************************\n\r");
    MSS_UART_polled_tx_string(gp_my_uart,(const uint8_t*)"******************** SmartFusion2 MMUART Example *********************\n\r");
    MSS_UART_polled_tx_string(gp_my_uart,(const uint8_t*)"**********************************************************************\n\r");
    MSS_UART_polled_tx_string(gp_my_uart,(const uint8_t*)"Characters typed will be echoed back.\n\r");

    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Echo back any characters received.
     */
    for (;;)
    {
        rx_size = MSS_UART_get_rx(gp_my_uart, rx_buff, sizeof(rx_buff));
        if( rx_size > 0 )
        {
            MSS_UART_polled_tx(gp_my_uart, rx_buff, sizeof(rx_buff));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cortex-M3 is a CPU core; it does not possess a UART. There are innumerable Cortex-M3-based microcontrollers, all with their own peripherals and clock trees, so it's impossible to say how to program _this_ UART or whether _this_ UART clock is related to CPU/bus clocks without at least knowing what MCU this is. There's also a slight possibility to bear in mind of it not being a software issue at all, but a hardware one with the external connection (inverted logic levels are not unheard of).

Comment: @Notlikethat its microsemi's smartfusion2

Comment: It is certainly derived from some clock in the system.  This should be documented in the datasheet or other reference manuals for the part.  Whatever clock is being used by the uart, which may or may not be under your program control, is then divided down to the desired rate, you need to focus on the code that is initializing the uart, compare clock selection to the documentation, and baud rate math.  Also where is your program setting 100mhz?

Comment: ahh, an fpga, so the 100mhz is probably not something you have to configure.  At the same time if you are doing fpga development you have a scope, what frequency is the uart outputting?

Comment: @dwelch the chip is having both fpga and cortex-m3 and i am using cortex-m3

Comment: Make sure the FPGA firmware that is loaded into the fabric matches what was used to generate the driver library for the software. If a clock was changed and both are not on the same page, you will have a mismatch and not get the correct baud rate.

Comment: Also, make sure if you're not using the Microsemi startup file that you call `SystemInit()` in your startup code. Also, check in the generated library header `sys_config_mss_clocks.h` and see that all the values here match what you expect (in Hz). These are the values that determine the baud rate divisor on the software side, so these need to match the actual clocks on the fabric side.

Answer (score 0):

Its been a long time but still, probably the reason you having junk data is your APB clock frequency. In README.txt of polled uart example, it says:

> The example project is built for a design using a SmartFusion2 Mss APB clock frequency of 83 Mhz. Trying to execute this example project on a different design will result in incorrect baudrate being used by MMUART0 or no output if MMUART0 is not enabled and connected.

The solution is: Replace "drivers_config/sys_config/sys_config_mss_clocks.h" file with your libero exported firmware. Or you can change it by manually.